Upload Error in Chrome: Request Entity Too Large – Tried Everything, Still Stuck
I'm facing a persistent issue with my WordPress site when trying to upload large files in Google Chrome. The error I keep encountering is:
413 Request Entity Too Large

I've tried troubleshooting this extensively, but nothing seems to work. Here's my setup and what I've done so far:
Setup:

Environment: WordPress in a Docker container.
Server: NGINX as a reverse proxy using NGINX Proxy Manager.
PHP: Running with a dedicated php.ini file.
Browser: Issue is consistent
Plugin: https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/

He is always uploading up to 100% and than i get this issue.
Uploading up to 100%
enter image description here
Different Browser, same way, same issue.
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    container_name: wp_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ""
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      - wpnet

  redis:
    image: redis:6-alpine
    container_name: wp_redis
    restart: always
    command: ["redis-server", "--appendonly", "yes"]
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/redis_data:/data
    networks:
      - wpnet

  app:
    image: 'jc21/nginx-proxy-manager:latest'
    container_name: proxy_manager
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
      - '127.0.0.1:81:81'
#      - '81:81'
    environment:
      DB_MYSQL_HOST: "db"
      DB_MYSQL_PORT: 3306
      DB_MYSQL_USER: "proxymanager"
      DB_MYSQL_PASSWORD: ""
      DB_MYSQL_NAME: "proxymanager"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/proxymanager/data:/data
      - ./volumes/proxymanager/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
    networks:
      - wpnet

  wordpress1:
    image: wordpress:latest
    container_name: wordpress1
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: "db:3306"
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: "wordpress1"
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ""
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: "wordpress1"
      WORDPRESS_DEBUG: "true"
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/wordpress1:/var/www/html
      - ./volumes/wordpress1/custom_configs/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
    networks:
      - wpnet

networks:
  wpnet:
    driver: bridge

What I've Tried:
1. PHP Configuration
I ensured the following settings in my php.ini:
memory_limit = 1G
upload_max_filesize = 5G
post_max_size = 5G
max_execution_time = 600

I verified these values using a phpinfo() page, and they are applied correctly.

2. NGINX Configuration
I added the following directive in NGINX Proxy Manager under the "Custom Nginx Configuration" for my WordPress site:
client_max_body_size 5G;

This didn't resolve the issue.

3. WordPress Configuration
In my wp-config.php, I added:
@ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '5G');
@ini_set('post_max_size', '5G');
@ini_set('memory_limit', '1G');
@ini_set('max_execution_time', '600');

I also enabled debugging with:
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true);

No relevant errors are logged.

4. Testing with Smaller Files
Uploads of smaller files work fine, so this seems related to size limits.

5. Error Logs

Docker Logs: Show no errors related to the issue.
PHP Logs: Nothing unusual or helpful logged.
NGINX Logs: No errors indicating the cause.


What I Need:
I’ve exhausted all the usual troubleshooting steps, but the issue persists. Has anyone encountered this before? Are there any browser-specific settings or additional configurations I might be missing for Chrome?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance for your insights.

Can you see in your logs if the error originates in the Wordpress or Nginx container? Also, since it's a server side error, which browser you use shouldn't matter.

No, no hints at all in the container logs.
I will analyze them again but I can't find anything. Especially since the problem is always reproducible with the compose file.
I also have the problem on another server.

######## - - [12/Dec/2024:16:30:34 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ai1wm_import&ai1wm_import=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 573 "https://########/wp-admin/admin.php?page=ai1wm_import" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/131.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
Thats the just one log after finish 100 upload

Maybe you can remove Nginx from the equation by exposing the Wordpress port directly. That should tell you if it's Wordpress or Nginx that doesn't like big files.
